# WebView shows lines when scrolling

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I have a webview which shows lines when scrolling up and down.
I load a simple piece of HTML into the webview and set the base URL to `/` and when scrolling in the web view, it will place horizontal lines even though none of those are present in the HTML.

I have attached a photo. The web view is supposed to show a white page with the text following text being repeated a couple of times.

> This is a test!

Instead, it also adds horizontal lines.

Does anyone know why this might occur and a possible fix for this?

[image: Webview showing horizontal lines when scrolling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the webview went just two pixels down below the text field. I guess this is essentially a bug in the webview.

Answer (score 0):

This is a WebView bug. For anyone who runs into this issue, you might want to try this workaround: add a hidden div to the html page.

```
<div style="height: auto; width: auto; top: -100px; left: -100px; visibility: hidden; position: fixed; overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap;opacity: 0 !important;pointer-events: none !important;"></div>
```